# Crashes are visible on firebase crashlytics console while debugging the build through Xcode but not on the enterprise build created through Jenkins

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I have this problem when trying to test my enterprise build.

Currently If I run the project in Debug mode, it runs fine.

When i check on Jenkins created enterprise build it doesn't show crashes on Firebase console.

I have updated my build setting Debug Information Format - Dwarf with dsym file.

Still no crash logs are visible.

Comment: Does your app crash at start? Did you trust to your enterprise certificate?

Comment: No app crashes on a button click. And yes i have trusted the enterprise certificate.